# Get the summation of two tables columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables. I want to write a query to calculate the total handling cost of each order using the tables in MySQL.

```
create table orders(id integer, packaging varchar(100), delivery 
varchar(100));

create table packaging_cost_tbl(packaging_type varchar(100), packaging_cost 
integer);

create table delivery_cos_tbl(delivery_type varchar(100), delivery_cost 
integer);

insert into orders(id, packaging, delivery) values(1, "Large", "Fast"),(2, 
"Small", "Fast"), (3, "Large", "Express"), (4, "Medium", "Standard"), (5, 
"Fragile", "Express"), (6, "Medium", "Fast"), (7, "Medium", "Standard");

insert into packaging_cost_tbl(packaging_type, packaging_cost) 
values("Small", 2), ("Medium", 5), ("Large", 8), ("Fragile", 10);

insert into delivery_cost_tbl(delivery_type, delivery_cost) 
values("Standard", 3), ("Fast", 7), ("Express", 15);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swUIl.png)

I have mentioned above create table queries and data insert queries for each tables. Output should be,

- Order ID
- Total handling cost( handling cost=packaging cost + delivery cost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd join the `orders` table on the two others and sum their costs:

```
SELECT id, packaging_cost + delivery_cost
FROM   orders o
JOIN   packaging_cost_tbl p ON o.pacakging = p.packaging_type
JOIN   delivery_cost_tbl d ON o.delivery = d.delivery_type
```